# Problems in designing AlertDialog

Tags: android, xml, android-alertdialog

I am trying to design AlertDialog, but I can't get rid of the black surrounding (As indicated by the red line), and the orange surrounding (As indicated by the blue line).
[image]

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

    <TextView
        android:src="@drawable/save_as"
        android:id="@+id/label_save_as"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="@string/save_as" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/filename"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:hint="@string/filename" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder saveAsBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater saveAsInflater = this.getLayoutInflater();       
    saveAsBuilder.setView(saveAsInflater.inflate(R.layout.saveas, null))
                 .setNeutralButton(R.string.saveAsImg, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // do something
                     }
               })
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.saveAsSkt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               // do something
                   }
            });      
    d = saveAsBuilder.create();
    d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    d.show();
```

How can I get rid of those?
BTW , I am using API 10.

Comment: post how you are setting the view in code ?

Comment: DialogFragments would give a better experience and allow you to make use of more modern methods.

Comment: I am using API 10 , and DialogFragments is for API 11 and above.

Comment: No, the support package allows dialogfragments back to api 4 http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html?utm_content=buffer11f41&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer

Answer (score 1):

Once try to change like this and try..

```
AlertDialog.Builder saveAsBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
```

setting the theme for the dialog to remove the black spaces

with using dialog..

```
    Dialog dialog=new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

for this you have to create two buttons in layout and implement listeners for that..

Comment: I am using API 10 , and the constructor is for API 11 and above.

Comment: How should I do it?  Dialog doesn't recognize setView();